Laravel 11 cors error- has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://laravel-react-survey-form-production.up.railway.app/api/signup' from origin 'https://laravel-react-survey-form.onrender.com' has been blyour textocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
someone help me I got this error when I try to test my deployed web app. note that Im using vite react js as my frontend and php laravel 11 as my backend.
here's my code:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->append(CorsMiddleware::class);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();


<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', '*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['https://laravel-react-survey-form.onrender.com'], // Consider specifying your frontend URL here
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];


<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return $response
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://laravel-react-survey-form.onrender.com')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With');
    }
}


I'm not sure 100%, but I think 'supports_credentials' should be set to true instead of false.
